# Extracting coefficients from clm object in ordinal package

Tags: r

I've fit a cumulative link model, using the `clm` function from the `ordinal` package in R. I need to get a coefficient estimate from the object, for further calculations. The value in question is `0.7527` from the table in this gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dc89dd0ba0d675238cd7

(Sorry I didn't output the table here, but I couldn't format it properly for some reason.)

I've inspected the object using the `str` function, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: you should clarify what you really want by providing an example data. This way you can get help very soon !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the vector of coefficients, you can use

```
model <- clm(blah blah blah)
coef(model)
```

and if you want the coef table, you can use:

```
coef(summary(model))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just looking for the one coefficient you can try the following, assuming your model is stored as `ordmod`.

```
tail(coef(ordmod), 1)
```

Comment: (we've gotta stop meeting like this :)